# DOCFX format tables using markdown without changing the template

Tags: markdown, docfx

Is it possible to change the layour of a table using markdown under `docfx`?

For example, the following table is not very good readable, because of the spacing between the columns. Event there is no alternating row color:

```
| Property | Description |
|---|---|
| URL | `/api/<version>/auth/login` |
| Method | `post` |
| Success | Http status *200* |
| Failure | Http-status *400/500* |
| Content/Media-Type | `application/json` |
| Authorization | *no* |
| Roles | - |
```

That is how it is looking in `doxfx`:

[image: MD-Table]

Some kind of expected behaviour:

[image: Expected]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We will extend the default template:

Create a file: `(Project Folder)\template\styles\main.js`

The default DocFX template uses Bootstrap and JQuery, so in main.js put the following:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
   $("table").addClass("table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed");
})
```

This makes the markdown tables identical to those in Api documentation.
To play with Bootstrap table styles, see http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tables.asp

Now, we add this template to docfx.json:
In docfx.json, Replace `"template": ["default"]` with `"template": ["default", "template"]`.

Comment: This issue has been fixed with [#957](https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/pull/957) and does not happen with the current version of docfx (2.15.3.0). So the above workaround should not be necessary anymore.